# Does any Teams Bot Activity handlers gets invoked if a Team or a channel is deleted because it's retention period is expired?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

There is a TeamsActivityHandler - OnTeamsChannelDeletedAsync(), this will be invoked by the Bot framework when a channel is deleted by the user. However, if a channel is deleted if it's retention period is expired does it still invoke the above mentioned activity handler?

Answer (score 1):

If a channel is deleted if it's retention period is expired it does not invoke the TeamsActivityHandler - OnTeamsChannelDeletedAsync().

This is by design behaviour.

If you wish you can suggest this feature here: [Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)